# How to show image in imageview as preview? Not the complete picture

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-imageview

I need to show an image in an imageview but not complete, just need a preview as seen in the image.

[image: imagen preview]

I have this code but it shows the complete image not a preview

xml code

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageView2"
 android:layout_width="100dp"
 android:layout_height="100dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:contentDescription="@string/img_adjunta" />
```

kotlin code

```
imageView2.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(fileComprimido))
```

Comment: add android:scaleType="centerCrop" to your image view. then your image will be shown like image in question

Comment: thaks works for me..